# Unable to install software on Ubuntu on 16.04

Tags: software-installation, error-handling

I am learning Linux and installed ubuntu few days ago. But when I tried to install bleachbit and flash plugin but I see the following while installing. Any help is highly appreciated.

[image: error message]

Comment: Did you try the commands suggested there?

Answer (score 0):

flash plugin is installed by installing "restricted extras" package found in software center.
as for the message it clearly states what is wrong. your sources are wrong or wrongly written (did you change anything in the file manually?). check the sources list. if you think all is ok update it and then force install. 
i am not sure why you need bleachbit but it is again available in software center. be careful when using it.

Answer (score 0):

This error message basically tells you what you should try first to fix your problem. What it leaves out is how you get to a terminal to enter those commands.

- hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to open a gnome-terminal
- enter (type or copy'n'paste) these commands and enter your password when asked for it:
  `sudo apt-get update`
- check for errors in the output

  - if there are any, you need to fix your apt sources files: `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and/or `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` after that, re-issue `sudo apt-get update` to check again.
  - if there are none: `sudo apt-get -f install` to fix missing or partly installed packages, and broken dependencies.